# If I do not pray but observe good manners, will I go to Jannah?

Tags: salat, akhirah

I'm a Muslim. It's kind of show off but I want to know in full detail: I do good deeds, give charity, keep fast, speak the truth, never cheat anyone, etc., but there's only one disadvantage in me that is I don't pray salah.  I only pray salah on Jumah afternoon and in Ramadan and on Eid prayers.

Please tell me if I go with the same routine in my whole life, will Allah give me Jannah after death without praying? Please tell me the answer. I told you everything that I do in my life.

Comment: Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) said that between a man and Kufr is abandonment of Salah. That is a very profound statement, that any God-fearing Muslim will hear and make sure that they never abandon Salah. In the Qur'an are described people who are in Hell and when asked why, say they didn't pray. If you do not want this to be your fate, then dear brother..... pray!!!!!!!

Comment: This is a very broad topic to address in a single answer. Is there any specific madhhab that you want to ask about (they do differ)? What is the reason that you do not pray (laziness, assumption that praying is less significant than good manners, ...)?

Comment: "Is there any specific madhhab that you want to ask about (they do differ)" - Would this not apply to ANY question ever asked on this site and so they're all too broad until they specifically mention a particular Madhab? You don't have a consistent way of approaching questions on this site.

Comment: @Muslimahياربالعالمين, no it would not apply to all questions as not all matters have differences among madhhabs, and not all matters have other consequences associated with them, and definitely not all matters have their evidence widely discussed (including _tamreed form_) as is the case with a person who does not pray all mandatory prayers. In any case, this was a question to the OP, not meant to spark ad hominems or debates over my consistency.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should know that praying is one of the most important part of Islam, I mean God has obligated these 5 daily prayers. This depends on your intention because

> If the one who does not pray does not do it because he denies that it is obligatory, even though he is aware that Allah has commanded that prayer be established, then he is a kaafir and an apostate according to the consensus of the ummah.
>
> If a person does not pray because he denies that it is obligatory out of ignorance on his part that it is obligatory, such as one who is new in Islam, he is not deemed to be a kaafir, but he is to be taught and instructed to pray.
>
> ...
>
> Ibn Qudaamah (may Allah have mercy on him) said:
>
> The one who does not pray must either deny that it is obligatory or not deny that this is the case. If he denies that it is obligatory, he must be examined further. If he is unaware of that, then he is one of those who are ignorant of that, such as one who is new in Islam or who grew up in the wilderness. He is to be informed and taught that it is obligatory, and he is not to be deemed a disbeliever, because he is excused.
>
> ...
>
> Ibn ‘Uthaymeen (may Allah have mercy on him) said:
>
> What appears to me to be the case is that he does not become a disbeliever unless he does not pray altogether, i.e., he never prays; as for the one who prays sometimes, he is not a disbeliever.
> <sub>[Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/194309)</sub>

Oh and remember, God will be very happy with you if you do truly obey Him:

> ”...The prayer is enjoined on the believers at fixed times”

If you do obey whatever He asks you to do then He’ll be very happy with you.

> “Ubada Ibn Shamit said, ‘I heard the Messenger of Allah -peace and prayer of Allah be upon him- said: “There are five prayers that Allah oblige to His slaves. So whoever performs it and does not abandon it due to underestimating it, will certainly get the promise of Allah, that He will place him in paradise. And whoever doesn’t perform it, will not get that promise, if Allah wishes, He will torture him, and if Allah wishes, He will forgive him and place him inside Paradise.” (Narrated by Abu Dawud, no. 1420, and classed valid by Al Albani).
>
> This hadith clearly indicates that a person who abandons prayer without denying its compulsoriness is not considered as a disbeliever, because a disbeliever will not enter the Paradise. And this is the opinion of the majority of Islamic scholars, and an opinion chosen by Sheikh Albani. (See: Silsilah Shahihah, 8/8). And Allah knows best.
> <sub>[whatisquran.com](https://whatisquran.com/989-ruling-for-those-who-abandon-the-prayer-shalat.html)</sub>

So, it is much better and much preferable if you do not miss them at all next time if you want to be safe from the punishment in grave and also from the punishment from the Day of Judgment. And thus, prayers are something which God loves the most as per Quran says and you can be His close friend if you do that by not missing the obligatory prayer and then you must also do continually good deeds till your end of life. How some people are His close friends? By praying regularly without stop and they took the thing of doing continually good deeds till their end as their hobby.

> Finally, Muhammad (peace be upon him) was told that Muslims must pray five times a day, and God added, “I have enforced My obligation and made it light for my servants. He who prays these five prayers will be rewarded as if he had prayed fifty. What I decree cannot be changed.”  **(Al-Bukhari)**

And praying also it helps you to remember God every day and it cleans you from every single past sin you made even if it is the sin of disbelief I suppose as per Quran says.

> Praying at the beginning of the day, lighten up your day. It gives you positive energy and guidance.
> <sub>[prayertimenyc.com](http://www.prayertimenyc.com/five-time-prayer-benefits-blessing/)</sub>

It also challenges you to wake up early in the morning for prayer. If you do pray then God will protect you all the day.

> Early in the morning, angels come down to witness the Muslims who are offering Fajr prayers. So, it is important to offer the Fajr prayer. Allah Almighty sent these angels, so try to offer prayers daily.
>
> ...
>
> If you miss the prayers early in the morning, your whole day will spoil. As you have missed the blessings of Allah at the start of the day.
>
> In the early morning, you earn the displeasure of Allah Almighty by missing the prayer.
>
> Allah will remove you from the list of pious people.
> <sub>[prayertimenyc.com](http://www.prayertimenyc.com/five-time-prayer-benefits-blessing/)</sub>

So, there are other many great benefits for why you’re praying the obligatory prayer.

Comment: While references are given, this answer is mostly just copy/pasted from them.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Sorry, I tried my best not to copy/paste.

Comment: I edited it and added them in.  (I don't see an answer to the question *If I do not pray but observe good manners, will I go to Jannah?*)